# question about a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have the next problem.Let $X$ be a random variable with Bernoulli's distribution $Ber(p)$. For every $t\geq0$ define the variable

$X_{t}=\begin{cases}
\cos (\pi t),  & \text{if $X$ = 0} \\
\sin(\pi t), & \text{if $X$ = 1}
\end{cases}$

I have to compute the distribution of $X_{t}$ and $E(X_{t})$ but I don't know how to do this, because I remember when I have the random variable with this distribution but I don't know how to apply in this case.

Comment: Another way to think about it: $$X_t = \cos(\pi t) + \left(\sin(\pi t) - \cos(\pi t)\right)\cdot X$$ Do you know how to find the distribution and expectation of $Y = a + b\cdot X$ for constants $a,b?$

Comment: For the expectation of $Y$ i think to apply the properties but for the distribution i will thinking, thank you very much :)